# Call to undefined function gcb() In wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Fatal error: Call to undefined function gcb() in D:\wamp\www\isee\wp-content\themes\isee\home.php on line 10

[image]

and this is my Code

```
*/
get_header(); 
echo homeslider_function(); ?>  
<article id="first-article"><?php echo gcb(1);?></article>
<article id="second-article"><?php echo gcb(2);?></article>
```

Line No 10 is gcb(1)

Comment: Where is `gcb()` defined? ... and what is it even supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to install the [Global Code Blocks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/global-content-blocks/) plugin.

From the [FAQ page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/global-content-blocks/faq/):

> **Can I use content blocks outside of posts and pages?**
>   Yes, just wrap it in the PHP function `<?php echo gcb(x);?>` where `x` is the content block ID. You can also use the longer form `<?php do_shortcode("[contentblock id=x]");?>`